# Source Indexing for static libraries. Perforce

Tags: perforce, pdb-files

The tasks is: 
1. build static libraries on one build machine
2. build dynamic library (linking static libraries from step 1) on another build machine. Second machine has no access to source control of static libraries.

I build static_library.lib with debug info (/Zi).
PDB file has been created. 
But it hasn't embeded the full paths to the source files.
So I use P4Index.cmd with the /Save switch:
P4Index.cmd -source="c:\project1\source" -symbols="c:\project1\out_Win32\Debug" /Save=c:/project1/srcinfo

It created files: p4_files.dat, servers.dat
As I can see p4_files.dat has pairs: filename and Perforce path.

Then I build dynamic_library.dll and link static_library.lib.
But there is an error when I run P4Index.cmd with the /Load switch:

ssindex.cmd [ERROR ] P4: Can't locate c:/project1/srcinfo\sd_files.dat in @INC ......

What is the file sd_files.dat ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `p4.pm` file that is located in the same folder as `P4Index.cmd`, it appears this might actually be a bug in the code.

```
sub LoadFileInfo {
    my $self = shift;
    my $dir  = shift;

    if ( -e "$dir\\p4_files.dat" ) {
        our $FileData1;
        require "$dir\\sd_files.dat";
        $$self{'FILE_LOOKUP_TABLE'} = $FileData1;
    } else {
        ::status_message("No Perforce information saved in $dir.\n");
    }

    return();
}
```

It looks like the require line should actually use `p4_files.dat` instead of `sd_files.dat`.

From reading [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it looks like *sd* is the default abstract name that is used to refer to the source control manager and so `sd_files.dat` is the abstract name for the dat file.

My above suspicions appear to be confirmed by the other source control pm files (cvs, svn, tfs and vss) all either don't have a require line or use the source control variant filename for it.

I tested the above change and the data is loaded without error.